# Test data returning Null

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, data

Test data creation:

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='TestAccount', Field__c='TestInfo');
    insert acct;

Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestFname1',LastName = 'TestLname1', Email = 'test@gmail.com', 
                              AccountId = acct.Id);
    insert con; 
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Custom Profile'];
User u = new User(/* Standard and Custom fields*/, ContactId = con.Id);

System.debug('user.contactId: ' +u.ContactId);
System.debug('user.con.FirstName: ' +u.Contact.FirstName);
```

I can able to get the ContactId, but not the FirstName. How to get the Firstname and other fields(User.Contact.Account.Name)?

I tried to query: `Select Contact.FirstName from User` which is working as expected, but why I cannot get this in my test data?

Comment: It is the Salesforce out-of-box User object's lookup field to the Contact object.

Comment: Unless you queried for the data back, you won't have access to the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created an instance of the user. Insert user record and separately perform SOQL query to retrieve `Contact.FirstName`

```
Account acct = new Account(Name='TestAccount', Field__c='TestInfo');
    insert acct;

Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestFname1',LastName = 'TestLname1', Email = 'test@gmail.com', 
                              AccountId = acct.Id);
    insert con; 
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Custom Profile'];
User u = new User(/* Standard and Custom fields*/, ContactId = con.Id);
insert u;    

System.debug('user.contactId: ' +u.ContactId);

//retrieve user record by SOQL
User userObj = [SELECT Contact.FirstName FROM User WHERE Id =:u.Id];

System.debug('user.con.FirstName: ' +userObj.Contact.FirstName);
```

Comment: But, by just calling the User object wont work here? Is this the only(query back) way again?

Comment: you could not retrieve reference field values until you execute a separate query

Comment: I thing you will get Mixed DML Exception because you are inserting setup and non setup object same time. use System.RunAs()

Comment: Well, I am actually trying to see/check the value that returns. Anyways I am using asserts statements to compare the values under `System.runAs( )`. Thanks for the heads-up.